# display empty row

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    workdate, 
    SUM(Sam) ttlsam 
FROM 
    Sah 
WHERE 
    workdate BETWEEN '01 May 2016' AND ' 05 May 2016' 
GROUP BY 
    workdate
```

I have execute the above command and result is

```
Workdate ttlsam
02 may   10
03 may   20
04 may   40
```

Here 01 and 05 May are not showing because those two date has no data. But I want like this. I mean although 01 and 05 may don't have data they needs to display 0 or null value in ttlsam field

```
01 may   0
02 may   10
03 may   20
04 may   40
05 may   0
```

Comment: SQL is not good at "filling in gaps" in data - display layers (reporting, etc) are generally where you want to fill in gaps in the data.  Otherwise you need a "date" table or something that you can left join to your _actual_ data.

Comment: You need a tally table. Tally tables are DB specific. Which one are you using

Comment: You can try using a outer apply with a function. The function would be responsible for calculating the SUM and returning that value for each workdate.

Answer (score 1):

This hopefully should help if you want to do it in MS SQL

```
DECLARE @DateTable TABLE 
(
    DateValue DATE NOT NULL 
)


DECLARE @StartDate DATE 
DECLARE @EndDate DATE 
DECLARE @WorkingDate DATE

SET @StartDate = '01 MAY 2016'
SET @EndDate = '30 MAY 2016'

SET @WorkingDate = @StartDate

WHILE @WorkingDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO @DateTable 
SELECT @WorkingDate


SET @WorkingDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@WorkingDate)

END



SELECT * FROM @DateTable


DECLARE @tempData TABLE 
(
    workdate date 
    , Sam int 

)


insert into @tempData
SELECT 
    '01 MAY 2016', 
    10 


insert into @tempData
SELECT 
    '01 MAY 2016', 
    10 

insert into @tempData
SELECT 
    '03 MAY 2016', 
    10 



SELECT 
    dates.DateValue, 
    SUM(ISNULL(Sam,0)) ttlsam 
FROM 
    @DateTable dates 
    left join 
        @tempData Sah 
        on 
        dates.DateValue = sah.workdate
WHERE 
    dates.DateValue BETWEEN '01 May 2016' AND ' 05 May 2016' 
GROUP BY 
    dates.DateValue
```

this would generate something like this:

```
DateValue   ttlsam
2016-05-01  20
2016-05-02  0
2016-05-03  10
2016-05-04  0
2016-05-05  0
```

Obviously without knowing what you actual data is behind the scenes I have assumed some things and limited the dataset to what you originally posted.

All I have done is created a `dates` table which is what you would use to be your summary table e.g. the dates you required. I have generated it for the first 30 days of may. But you could have it for a year etc. just change the values for the start and end dates.

We then just iterate through the dates and add them into the table.

Once this done you run your same query but with a join to this temp table you created. It will then group and sum the values. If there is no value present then it will do an ISNULL check and put a zero in it's place.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: It's pretty easy to create a Date Series without temp tables or iteration in SQL SERVER by using master..spt_value DATEDIFF and DATE ADD. [See this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485324/calendar-tally-table)

Comment: Dear David Thanks. Actually I am using this query with a record set like this using VB   Creaters1("select sum(Sam) from Sah where date between '01 may 2016' and (05 may 2016) group by workdate"). From here I want transfer data to excel sheet but as 01 may data is blank that's why 02 may data becomeing on 01 may cell.

Answer (score 0):

To get a time series without holes, suitable, for example, for graphing *ttlsam* vs. *workdate*, you need to explicitly construct all dates of interest. [An example for Oracle](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:14582643282111).

Then you can select the sum of your *Sam* column for each date of interest rather than for each date in the original table. 
Supposing you have populated a *dates_of_interest* table with a *d* column:

```
select d, sum(Sam) from dates_of_interest left outer join Sah on d=workdate group by d
```

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, on SAH table I want to put a condition . such as line_code like 'K%' here line_code is column name in SAH table. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
    dates.DateValue, 
    SUM(ISNULL(Sam,0)) ttlsam 
FROM 
    @DateTable dates 
    left join 
        @tempData Sah 
        on 
        dates.DateValue = sah.workdate
WHERE 
    dates.DateValue BETWEEN '01 May 2016' AND ' 05 May 2016' 
GROUP BY 
    dates.DateValue.  I want to add another condtion from SAH table such as "line like 'K%' what should I do.

Comment: Add your conditions to the WHERE clause. The purpose of the left outer join is adding artificial records for "missing" dates;and secondarily discarding records with a date you aren't interested in; you can filter the join exactly like the original table.